# How to switch streams based on some EventStream changes in Bacon

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, bacon.js, reactive-streams

Consider this example from http://baconjs.github.io/

```
var up   = $('#up').asEventStream('click');
var down = $('#down').asEventStream('click');

var counter =
  // map up to 1, down to -1
  up.map(1).merge(down.map(-1))
  // accumulate sum
    .scan(0, function(x,y) { return x + y });

// assign observable value to jQuery property text
counter.assign($('#counter'), 'text');
```

What if I have one more button for resetting counter and an event stream from this button clicks. How do I switch counter stream based on reset clicks stream to reset counter? I know that I have to use .flatMapLatest method, but referring this example I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `flatMapLatest` here. You can use a powerful and a much simpler [Bacon.update](http://baconjs.github.io/api.html#bacon-update) as in this example we have a simple state machine.

```
var up    = $('#up').asEventStream('click');
var down  = $('#down').asEventStream('click');
var reset = $('#reset').asEventStream('click');

var counter = Bacon.update(0,
  [up],    function (prev, unused) { return prev + 1; },
  [down],  function (prev, unused) { return prev - 1; },
  [reset], function (prev, unused) { return 0; }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `#reset` is a button for resetting

```
var up   = $('#up').asEventStream('click');
var down = $('#down').asEventStream('click');
var reset = $('#reset').asEventStream('click');

var counter = reset.flatMapLatest(function () {
    return up.map(1).merge(down.map(-1))
             .scan(0, function(x,y) { return x + y });
});

counter.assign($('#counter'), 'text');
```